# ¿Cómo evitar que al ejecutar una función en JS se refresque la pagina y me muestre los resultados en otra pestaña del navegador?

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando un contador de palabras y al lanzar la función "contar" la página se refresca y me muestra los resultados en otra pestaña del navegador cuando quiero que se muestren debajo de los botones "contar" y "restaurar".

Html:

```
<div class="areaDeTexto">
    <textarea cols="30" rows="15" id="texto"></textarea> <br>
    <button onclick="contar()">Contar</button>
    <button onclick="restaurar()">Restaurar</button>
    <input type="text" id="num" style="width:100px;">
</div>
```

JS:

```
var texto = document.getElementById("texto");
let num   = document.getElementById("num");

function contar() {
    var words  = texto.value.split(' ');
    num.value = words.length;
    let wordsList = {};

    words.forEach(function(word){
        word = clearString(word);
        if(wordsList[word]) {
            wordsList[word] += 1;
        } else{
            wordsList[word] = 1;
        }
    });

    let wordsListSize = Object.keys(wordsList).length;

    document.write("En el texto hay " +wordsListSize+ " palabras diferentes. </br>");


    document.write(" Estas palabras se repiten en el texto: </br>");
    for (var j = 0; j < words.length; j++){
        for (var l = j+1; l < words.length; l++){
            if(words[j] == words[l]){
                document.write(words[l]+ "</br>");
            }
        }
    }
}

function clearString(string){
    let replace = string.toLowerCase().replace(/[,.!;]/g, '');
    return replace;
}

function restaurar(){
    texto.value = "";
    num.value   = "";
}
```

Los resultados de las funciones sí los arroja correctamente solo que no me los muestra en mi página principal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para imprimir los resultados de un archivo JavaScript en el HTML, siempre es mejor usar el `innerHTML`.

Puedes aprender a usarlo con esta documentación: [element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

De hecho, en trabajos de producción usar el `innerHTML` es lo más recomendable.

En cambio, el `document.write` es casi siempre útil solamente para practicar y empezar a aprender a usar JavaScript.

Por lo tanto, intenta agregar un nuevo `<div>` debajo de los botones e imprimir los resultados ahí reemplazando todos los `document.write` de la siguiente manera:

```js
var texto = document.getElementById("texto");
let num   = document.getElementById("num");
let results   = document.getElementById("results");

function contar() {
    var words  = texto.value.split(' ');
    num.value = words.length;
    let wordsList = {};

    words.forEach(function(word){
        word = clearString(word);
        if(wordsList[word]) {
            wordsList[word] += 1;
        } else{
            wordsList[word] = 1;
        }
    });

    let wordsListSize = Object.keys(wordsList).length;

    results.innerHTML = "En el texto hay " +wordsListSize+ " palabras diferentes. </br>";


    results.innerHTML = results.innerHTML + "Estas palabras se repiten en el texto: </br>";
    for (var j = 0; j < words.length; j++){
        for (var l = j+1; l < words.length; l++){
            if(words[j] == words[l]){
                results.innerHTML = results.innerHTML + words[l]+ "</br>";
            }
        }
    }
}

function clearString(string){
    let replace = string.toLowerCase().replace(/[,.!;]/g, '');
    return replace;
}

function restaurar(){
    texto.value = "";
    num.value   = "";
    results.innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<div class="areaDeTexto">
    <textarea cols="30" rows="15" id="texto"></textarea> <br>
    <button onclick="contar()">Contar</button>
    <button onclick="restaurar()">Restaurar</button>
    <input type="text" id="num" style="width:100px;">
    <div id="results" />
</div>
```

Comment: Tenias razón, muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda! :)